# $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space has a lebesgue measurable basis

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

After studying some measure theory i found this sentence without proof.

$$\mathbb R \quad \text{as a} \quad \mathbb Q \quad \text{vector space has a lebesgue measurable basis}$$

**A hint is given**: Analyse the family of all $\mathbb Q$-linear independent subsets of the Cantor set for maximal elements.

I have zero clues on how to progress with this so if anyone is interested in checking this I would gladly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: What have you found out about $\mathbb Q$-linearly independent subsets of the Cantor set? Is there a maximal one? If so, what do you know about its $\mathbb Q$-linear span?

Comment: I think this might help - any real number on $[0,2]$ is a sum of two Cantor numbers.

Comment: @bof to be honest I am completely lost here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could prove first that the Cantor set is $C=\{\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x_n}{3^n}:\ x_n\in \{0,2\} \}$. With this in mind you can prove what TZakrevskiy said in the comments. This means that
$Span(C)=\mathbb{R}$, because $\mathbb{R}=Span[0,2]=Span(C)$. By Zorn's lemma you can find a maximal linearly independent subset $\beta$ inside of $C$. You can see that $Span(\beta)\supseteq C$ so $Span(\beta)=\mathbb{R}$.

This concludes the result because every subset of a null set is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: I have proven both before but i dont really see on how to continue from this. Sorry for bothering so much but this messes with me alot

Comment: Dont worry, i edited the proof, i hope is more useful now.

Comment: I need to read about zorns lemma again etc. this was the part I am still missing to fully understand this. Thank you alot for the effort